# BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize not being honored?

Tags: android

I have a photo on disk with dimensions 2560 x 1920. This is often too large to load into memory, so I'm trying to use BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize to conserve memory. From the docs:

> inSampleSize: If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

This is how I use it:

```
BitmapFactory.Options optsDownSample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
optsDownSample.inSampleSize = 3;

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, optsDownSample);
```

but the app still sometimes crashes on the last line there, and from logcat I can see it's trying to allocate ~5mb, and I suspect this is because the downsampling is not really being honored.

Anyone else know what could be going on here, am I using inSampleSize incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: It may be that the inSampleSize should be a power of 2? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966

Comment: Huh could be, the docs just say that powers of two are easier to honor, I will give it a shot, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yeah seems to be taking now, thanks!

Comment: Hhhhmmmm... I was trying to make he comment above an answer but Stackoverflow forced it to be a comment (as it was so sort)? Can you still give me "reputation"?

Comment: Try to post your comment/solution as an answer, maybe he will accept it.

Comment: Yeah please post as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling understanding how to use the `BitmapFactory.Options`, based on all the documentation I've read I believe you are just missing the `optsDownSample.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` as indicated on the [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) site.

Best of lucks!